# UIImage size managment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image that is used in multiple places within my IOS app at various sizes. Should I be using one large image in conjunction with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit to scale it (currently this approach seems to cause distortion on the smaller images despite being scaled to proportionate sizes) or should I have multiple versions of the image at different sizes.

It seems a little extreme to have so many copies of one image e.g. my_image_ipad, my_image_small, my_image_large, my_image_medium.

Answer (score 1):

In general it depends on what it takes to get the look and quality you want.  Some images will scale from a large image to a small image with little or no visual loss in quality.  Others, as you've found, scale poorly, especially at extreme scales.  You're really going to have to just try various solutions and see what works.  One way you can almost always cut down on application size is to remove the non-@2x artwork and ship with just the @2x.

Comment: My biggest concern is maintainability if I had lots of images. As it would take a lot of time to update them all etc. It seems odd that a relatively simply image is blurry after being scaled down to a proportionate size. Maybe I am doing it incorrectly. I am trying to do it using the storyboards.

Comment: Many images don't scale well at extreme scales, even though they're proportionate and powers of two.  It all depends on the image.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use one image, because it will make your app "lighter", but this may cause your code to become bigger.